# PhpExcell changes a value in my converted file

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, xlsx

What the hell! I convert a long table from xlsx to csv with PhpExcel. Everything was fine, but now, I'm a bit puzzled, because a value has changed in my last file from 772,68 to 772.6799999999999.

I use the CSV files for reporting, and this value is too long, and the (remote) interpreter can't understand that.

I can't understand what happend.

Here is the source:

```
function convertXLStoCSV($infile,$outfile) {
    $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);


    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);
    $max = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2:B'.$max.'')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('YYYY.MM.DD');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AP2:AP'.$max.'')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('YYYY.MM.DD');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AQ2:AQ'.$max.'')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('YYYY.MM.DD');


    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->setDelimiter(';'); 
    $objWriter->save($outfile);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPExcel hasn't changed any value. The value stored in the file you're loading is a floating point value 772.6799999999999, you probably had a number format mask on it in the original file to only display it to 2dp, but as you're not loading the number format masks (because you're using `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`) then that masking can't be applied when you save as csv.

Comment: Thanks. I find an other solution:

this is worked for me:

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AO2:AO'.$max.'')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00);

Comment: Well ensuring that a number format mask is applied will resolve the problem, whether it's the mask from the original file, or one that you apply yourself before the save